# display automatic turns to the side (sensor)

Tags: 18.04, display, settings, automatic

If i cant my laptop to the side the display turns in this direction. I dont need that because I have no touchscreen. How can I disable that?
My system:
HP Probook 650 G2
Ubuntu 18.04

Thank you
Raphael